# не получается настроить в docker-compose порт подключения к postgres через pgadmin4

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin4

задаю порт для контейнера 3002, a из pgadmin почему то подключаюсь к порту 5432 (также при попытке подключится к 3002 кидает ошибку)

конфиг в основном скапирован из доков elestio/pgadmin

```
version: ' v2.23.3-desktop.2'
services:
  xy:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '3002:5432'

  pgadmin4:
    image: elestio/pgadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@email.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin@email.com
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 8080
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    volumes:
      - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

разве порт не должен быть 3002 ????

Comment: [Port mapping](https://yuminlee2.medium.com/docker-port-mapping-12dd1d94fa54)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эти порты прокидываются для внешнего использования:

- Извне (вне докера) можно подключится к базе через port host-a `3002` - который прокидывается на порт `5432`

```
ports:
  - '3002:5432'
```

Это можно проверить указав:

```
ports:
  - '3002:3002'
```

внутри контейнера в логах будет не измененный port `5432`:

```
2024-02-05 22:59:12 2024-02-05 19:59:12.575 UTC [1] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  для приёма подключений по адресу IPv4 "0.0.0.0" открыт порт 5432
2024-02-05 22:59:12 2024-02-05 19:59:12.575 UTC [1] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  для приёма подключений по адресу IPv6 "::" открыт порт 5432
2024-02-05 22:59:12 2024-02-05 19:59:12.577 UTC [1] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  для приёма подключений открыт Unix-сокет "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

Что бы изменить port на котором работает база внутри сети докера,
можно указать параметр для контейнера `postgresql`:

```
environment:
  PGPORT: '3002'
```

Тогда в логах будет нужный port `3002` и в pgadmin можно будет приконектиться к базе через него:

```
2024-02-05 23:08:46 2024-02-05 20:08:46.362 UTC [1] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  для приёма подключений по адресу IPv4 "0.0.0.0" открыт порт 3002
2024-02-05 23:08:46 2024-02-05 20:08:46.363 UTC [1] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  для приёма подключений по адресу IPv6 "::" открыт порт 3002
2024-02-05 23:08:46 2024-02-05 20:08:46.364 UTC [1] СООБЩЕНИЕ:  для приёма подключений открыт Unix-сокет "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.3002"
```

Comment: спасибо, завтра гляну, отпишусь/приму ответ.

Comment: спасибо еще раз за ответ, если не трудно можно ссылку где ты увидел переменную среды PGPORT, в описании его нету, в readme тоже не нашел, мне бы понять где в дальнейшем такие вещи искать, а то выходит так что доки не полные либо я пока не разобрался с images и доками для них

Comment: все разобрался, надо в самой докумнтации техналогии смотреть

Comment: Не за что, да в доке postgresql есть, оставлю [здесь](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html)

Answer (score 0):

Вот сделанный для вас docker compose:

```
version: 'v2.23.3-desktop.2'
services:
  xy:
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '3002:5432'

  pgadmin4:
    image: elestio/pgadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: admin@email.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin@email.com
      PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 3002  # Измените порт прослушивания на 3002
    ports:
      - '8080:3002'  # Пробросьте порт 3002 из контейнера pgadmin4 на порт 8080 хоста
    volumes:
      - ./servers.json:/pgadmin4/servers.json
```

У вас была ошибка с настройкой портов

[image: Всё работает]

Comment: нечего не поменялось, да и изменение порта pgadmin как то должно повлеять на postgres?

Comment: @Armen тогда пожалуйста покажите логи или что у вас не так. Я вам демонстрировал, что у меня все работает

Comment: спасибо, внизу уже дали ответ каторый интересует.